# How can I pass an object from inside run_callbacks to the after_callback scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

Our object has several defined lifecycle callback methods. In each method that triggers a callback, an Event object is created for tracking purposes. The lifecycle events are defined like this:

```
 @@LIFECYCLE_CALLBACKS = [
  :send_email,
  :start_time,
  :end_time,
  :review
 ].each do |callback|
     define_model_callbacks callback
     define_method callback do
       run_callbacks callback do
         #The Event object is created here
         track_lifecycle_action callback
       end
     end
   end
```

In some of the lifecycle methods, I need to add additional information to the Event object. I would like to attach blocks to the generated callback like this:

```
after_send_email :add_additional_details_to_event
```

How can I modify my code to always pass the Event object that is created inside the run_callbacks block into the context of the block being run by the after_callback callback? I don't think I can assume that `self.events.last` will always return the correct Event object.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a little bit of time thinking on this, and the best solution I've come up with looks like this:

```
@@LIFECYCLE_CALLBACKS = [
  :send_email,
  :start_time,
  :end_time,
  :review
 ].each do |callback|
     define_model_callbacks callback
     define_method callback do
       @event = track_lifecycle_action callback
       run_callbacks callback do
       end
     end
   end
```

Now when I register a method with a callback like review

```
after_review :print_event
```

I've realised that all the blocks passed to the callback macros share the same instance scope, so I can do something like this

```
def print_event
  puts @event
end
```

Is this dangerous? Is there a more elegant way of accomplishing my task?